# xamarin forms FlowListView not showing data from List

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a FlowListView control that is not displaying the items from a list. For test purposes I just wanted to display file path of the photo as a label.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms.Controls"
        xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
        x:Class="TamarianApp.ImagePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" x:Name="image_gallary" ItemsSource="{Binding photos}" HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding filepath}" TextColor="Black" Margin="20" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the backend:

```
  public partial class ImagePage : ContentPage
  {
        public List<Photo> photos = App.rug.photos

        public ImagePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "Photos";
        }
   }
```

'App.rug.photos' is a List of the Photo class which contains the string field 'filepath'. Debugging shows field 'photos' is not empty and contains the data from 'App.rug.photos.'

Please Help.

Comment: Add a "ViewModel" class and set it as the BindingContext of the page. You should be following the MVVM pattern if using Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

It may be to do with how you are assigning the list,  you need to make sure that the list is a Property in order for the binding to work correctly.

Try..

```
public partial class ImagePage : ContentPage
  {
        public List<Photo> photos {get; set;}

        public ImagePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "Photos";
            photos = App.rug.photos 
        }
   }
```

You may also need to set the binding context

```
public partial class ImagePage : ContentPage
  {
        public List<Photo> photos {get; set;};

        public ImagePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
            Title = "Photos";
            photos = App.rug.photos 
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public ObservableCollection<object>() photos;
...
var oc = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
foreach (var item in App.rug.photos)
    oc.Add(item);
photos = oc as ObservableCollection<object>;
```

I was having trouble with `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`, but solved it by using `ObservableCollection<object>`.